# Adding 3rd party application into Settings.apk

Tags: java, android

Recently I'm building a AOSP ROM from source. What I wanted to do is, add a 3rd party application into Settings app and It should be launched only from Settings and it should be invisible from Launcher.
Here's what I did, It fails everytime.
Removed these lines from apps AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

and added below lines in SettingsActivity.java from Settings app.

```
 if (KA_FRAGMENT.equals(fragmentName)) {
    Intent kaIntent = new Intent();
    kaIntent.setClassName("com.cyborg.manager", "com.cyborg.manager.activities.MainActivity");
    startActivity(kaIntent);
    finish();
    return null;
}
```

Also added below lines in AndroidManifest.xml of Settings

```
<activity android:name="Settings$KActivity"
        android:label="@string/hit_perform"
        android:icon="@drawable/hit_performance_icon"
        android:taskAffinity="" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="com.android.settings.SHORTCUT" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter android:priority="1">
        <action android:name="com.android.settings.action.SETTINGS" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="com.android.settings.category"
        android:value="com.android.settings.category.urom" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.android.settings.FRAGMENT_CLASS"
        android:value="com.android.settings.ka" />
</activity>
```

Although, it works fine when 3rd party app is visible in launcher

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play with custom ROM I'd recommend getting familiar with Android fundamentals first.

What makes you activity shown by launcher is this `<intent-filter>`

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="com.android.settings.SHORTCUT" />
 </intent-filter>
```

especially these two lines:

```
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

so remove them and you are done.

Comment: That's what I did for the first time, but It only worked for removing app icon from Launcher. Whenever I tried to click on Preference screen from settings, the 3rd party app opens for a second and error pops up to close the app. I just want to integrate app into settings and remove it from the launcher. If you could tell me or redirect me to right page, it will be helpful.